# How come I can't count downwards on an array in Java?

Tags: java

I am currently trying to take the elements of an array and reverse its order in Java. How come I cannot print the elements of the array by counting downwards using a for loop without changing the actual ordering of elements in my array?

```
private void printArray(int[] array) {
    for (int i = array.length; i >= 0; i--){
        println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `array.length - 1`.  The array length tells you overall how many elements are there - such as an array with 1 element has 1 - but that array would only have a position 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Array indices start at `0` and end at `array.length - 1`. Here, you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBOundsException` since your first read is past the end of the array (`int i = array.length;`).

Do:

```
for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    println(array[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for (int i = array.length - 1; -1 != i; --i){
```

As indexes start from 0

Comment: Why `-1 != i;`? His comparison looks ok.

Comment: Doing an equality or non-equality is cheaper than using comparison operator.

Comment: @EdHeal Why do you think that? It's not true on most CPUs.

Comment: @Jesper - It is true. Fire both bit patterns through an XOR gate and check for zero. Do not need to take into account of twos complement etc.